# php ftp_get() returns permission denied

Tags: php, ftp, cron

I'm using a ftp upload script to transfer one server to another. It works fine in a browser window, and works great from an ssh command line by running:
php  /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/ftp_shell.php

but when I run the exact same command from a cron, I get this:

PHP Warning:  ftp_get(ftp.tmp): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/ftp_shell.php on line 516
PHP Warning:  ftp_get(): Error opening ftp.tmp in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/ftp_shell.php on line 516

I looked on line 516, which is:

```
    if((ftp_get($ftp_from,"ftp".$tmp.".tmp",$fname,FTP_BINARY) ||
        ftp_get($ftp_from,"ftp".$tmp.".tmp",$fname,FTP_ASCII)) &&
       (ftp_put($ftp_to,$fname,"ftp".$tmp.".tmp",FTP_BINARY) ||
        ftp_put($ftp_to,$fname,"ftp".$tmp.".tmp",FTP_ASCII)) &&
       ftp_site($ftp_to,"chmod ".base_convert($chmod,10,8)." $fname") &&
       f_size()&&unlink("ftp".$tmp.".tmp")) {echoout(" (".$size_b." bytes) ok<br>");$count_f++;}
```

I know that it's writing the file to a temp file, but why would it allow me to do it in the browser and command line, but not a cron?

Comment: Are you using user name/password in browser session?

Comment: what linux distro are you on? also can you paste your cron line?

Comment: No user/pass. 
CentOS 6.

Comment: cron line:
* * * * * php /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/ftp_shell.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the temp file was created by php script(apache user) and you want to read it from cron job (root user). Temp files are not readable from one users to others for security reasons.

You have to change your cron job to be executed by apache user, or you can alter the permissions of the temp file to be readable for everyone, but this is not recommended as any other procesess could read the file.

Comment: the temp file is created on the fly, then deleted when it's not needed anymore. How do I change the user to apache? Is this possbiel in php?

Answer (score 1):

Jobs run under cron will have a different default working directory than whatever you're running from a webserver and/or the command line. Most likely whatever directory IS being used as the default while in cron does not have appropriate permissions for the cron job to use.

Try using absolute paths, e.g.

```
ftp_get($ftp_from,"/real/path/to/file/ftp".$tmp.".tmp",$fname,FTP_BINARY)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

instead of the relative paths you're using otherwise.

Comment: The error is "Permission denied" which indicates the file is there, just that don't have permission to read it.

Comment: possibly, but you get permission denied as well if any of the directories leading up the file aren't readable as well. consider it the equivalent of a pile of gold in the middle of a bank vault. it's just sitting there for the taking, but first you have to get into the vault.

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

`PHP Warning: ftp_get(ftp.tmp): failed to open stream`

and the line is:

`if((ftp_get( $ftp_from, "ftp" . $tmp . ".tmp", $fname ...`

so the error must be in a empty `$tmp` variable